# Rasterize polygons using gdal/ogr python API

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, rasterization

My understanding so far is that 'gdal' is used for raster data and 'ogr' for vector data. Given this I have been trying to rasterize a polygon data set (output raster metadata is given by a raster template). I have tried with the following piece of code, but I am afraid that there are quite a few things that are probably wrong.

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr

#Geodatabase and Polygon Feature Class name
path_gdb = r'Z:\......\Flood_Defences.gdb'
fc = r'FloodDefences'

#Reading polygons with ogr
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("OpenFileGDB")
gdb = driver.Open(path_gdb, 0)
flood_def = gdb.GetLayer(fc)
sr = flood_def.GetSpatialRef()

#Path to the tif file where the rasterized polygons will be stored
out_path = r'Z:\.....\raster.tif'


#Template raster and its information
template_path = r'Z:\.......template.tif'
raster = gdal.Open(template_path)
gt = raster.GetGeoTransform()
ndv = raster.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()
proj = raster.GetProjection()
driver = raster.GetDriver().ShortName
cols = raster.RasterXSize
rows = raster.RasterYSize
count = raster.RasterCount
dtype = gdal.GetDataTypeName(raster.GetRasterBand(1).DataType)


#Rasterize polygons
gdal.Rasterize(out_path, gdb, format=driver, outputType=gdal.gdalconst.GDT_Float32,                                      
               creationOptions=['COMPRESS=LZW', 'BIGTIFF=YES', 'blockxsize=256', 'blockysize=256'],  
               outputSRS='EPSG:29902', layers=fc, width=cols, height=rows, xRes=gt[1], yRes=gt[5],
               noData=ndv, targetAlignedPixels=True, allTouched='YES', burnValues=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-177-7fcf99466a93> in <module>
      3                outputSRS='EPSG:29902', layers=fc,
      4                width=cols, height=rows, xRes=gt[1], yRes=gt[5], noData=ndv,
----> 5                targetAlignedPixels=True, allTouched='YES', burnValues=1)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py in Rasterize(destNameOrDestDS, srcDS, **kwargs)
   1137 
   1138     if _is_str_or_unicode(destNameOrDestDS):
-> 1139         return wrapper_GDALRasterizeDestName(destNameOrDestDS, srcDS, opts, callback, callback_data)
   1140     else:
   1141         return wrapper_GDALRasterizeDestDS(destNameOrDestDS, srcDS, opts, callback, callback_data)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py in wrapper_GDALRasterizeDestName(*args)
   3488 def wrapper_GDALRasterizeDestName(*args):
   3489     """wrapper_GDALRasterizeDestName(char const * dest, Dataset srcDS, GDALRasterizeOptions options, GDALProgressFunc callback=0, void * callback_data=None) -> Dataset"""
-> 3490     return _gdal.wrapper_GDALRasterizeDestName(*args)
   3491 class GDALBuildVRTOptions(_object):
   3492     """Proxy of C++ GDALBuildVRTOptions class."""

TypeError: in method 'wrapper_GDALRasterizeDestName', argument 2 of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *'
```

Also, neither sr nor proj seems to give the information I need about the reference system. In the end I had to hard-code it in the function call ('EPSG:29902').

Comment: I find the documentation not particularly helpful (https://gdal.org/python/)

Comment: Gdal autotests are made with Python and they can also be used as examples about anything that can be done with GDAL. Or at least about anything that is automatically tested after every commit to the code base. Check if this has some value for you https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/alg/rasterize.py.

Answer (score 2):

The error refers to the Type of the object you passed to GetDataTypeName, the line in question is:

```
dtype = gdal.GetDataTypeName(raster.GetRasterBand(1).DataType)
```

For the Rasterize function and its arguments, you can see the help for guessing which Types the function expects:

```
In [2]: gdal.Rasterize?
Signature: gdal.Rasterize(destNameOrDestDS, srcDS, **kwargs)
Docstring:
Burns vector geometries into a raster
Arguments are :
  destNameOrDestDS --- Output dataset name or object
  srcDS --- a Dataset object or a filename
Keyword arguments are :
  options --- return of gdal.RasterizeOptions(), string or array of strings
  other keywords arguments of gdal.RasterizeOptions()
If options is provided as a gdal.RasterizeOptions() object, other keywords are ignored.
File:      /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py
Type:      function
```

source and destination datasets can be passed as objects or filenames, so you can use gdb or path_gdb for source.

Other options are passed to gda.RasterizeOptions:

```
In [3]: gdal.RasterizeOptions?
Signature:
gdal.RasterizeOptions(
    options=None,
    format=None,
    outputType=0,
    creationOptions=None,

...

  format --- output format ("GTiff", etc...)
  outputType --- output type (gdalconst.GDT_Byte, etc...)

...

  bands --- list of output bands to burn values into
```

outputType refers to the type of the output pixels, i.e. for float32 use gdal.gdalconst.GDT_Float32

bands take a list of output bands. (not a count)

for other parameters, run `gdal.RasterizeOptions?` in iPython or jupyter, and read the docs.

Comment: I run the code instruction by instruction using jupyter notebook. gdal.GetDataTypeName(raster.GetRasterBand(1).DataType) returns 'Float32'. If that's not what I need to assign to outputType, then what is it? 0?
I don't understand your comment about src and dst.

Comment: @PitrakoJunior i updated the answer, hope it helps now

Comment: Thanks. I have now changed that and it seems it goes through that bit and throws a different error further down. I have updated the description.

Comment: @PitrakoJunior Updated again, you should read the function docs and check your parameters before going on. please.